# tvos How to always focus specific tableViewCell

Tags: ios, focus, tvos, focus-engine

I've creating tvOs app and had stucked with focus engine.

I have tableview, and set `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` true.  And I have to override `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView`. When I focus first time, `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView` get called, and I get the cell focused, what I need. But in other times I get last focused indexpath. When I define `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` to false, `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView`not being called.

What I need to do, to focus only cells, what I need?

Answer (score 3):

`indexPathForPreferredFocusedView` is called only once when the view is about to get focus for the very first time or during reload.

If you are expecting to get some other Focus behaviour, you can try with `preferredFocusEnvironments` to get your focus behavior.

Also, it will focus to the last focused `IndexPath` because that is the default behavior in tvOS. The variable `restoreFocusAfteViewTransition` is set to true by default. You can change this to false in `ViewController` and check if you are able to achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score -3):

Override the below function and return indexpath that you want to focus.

```
override func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in tableView: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {}
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCe8A.png)

Comment: I've override this function, but it get called only once

Comment: see the demo pic